# How to convert multiple files with ffmpeg to GIFs

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I found in this forum [Convert-mp4-to-gif](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/394777-convert-mp4-to-gif) at good batch-code for converting videos to GIF-files by just dragging and dropping the files onto the batch files. The problem is I can only drop one file at the time, whereas I have maybe hundres of files, which I just want my computer to work on.

The code is as seen here:

```batch
@echo off
::** create animated GIF w/ optimized palette
::
:: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#gif-2
:: http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html
:: http://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality

if not exist "%~dpnx1" goto :EOF
cd "%~dp1" 

::** generate palette
@echo on
@echo.
"c:\program files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" ^
 -v warning -i "%~nx1" ^
 -vf "palettegen" ^
 -y tmp-palette.png

::** generate GIF
@echo.
"c:\program files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" ^
 -v warning -i "%~nx1" ^
 -i tmp-palette.png ^
 -lavfi "[0][1:v] paletteuse" ^
 "%~n1.gif"
@echo off

del /q tmp-palette.png

if errorlevel 1 pause
goto :eof
```

I have absolutely no idea how to program batch files, and this code was just something I found online which worked for me. Can anybody help me adding the needed code for making me able to drag and drop multiple files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
::** create animated GIF w/ optimized palette
::
:: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#gif-2
:: http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html
:: http://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747767/how-to-convert-multiple-files-with-ffmpeg-to-gifs

set "ffmpeg=%ProgramFiles%\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

for %%A in (%*) do (
    if exist "%%~A" pushd "%%~dpA" && (

        @echo:
        @echo "%%~A"
        @echo  generate palette

        "%ffmpeg%" ^
         -v warning -i "%%~nxA" ^
         -vf "palettegen" ^
         -y tmp-palette.png

        @echo  generate GIF
        "%ffmpeg%" ^
         -v warning -i "%%~nxA" ^
         -i tmp-palette.png ^
         -lavfi "[0][1:v] paletteuse" ^
         "%%~nA.gif"

        del /q tmp-palette.png
        if errorlevel 1 pause

        popd
    )
)
```

Updated with a simple `for` loop. View `for /?` for help documentation.